# XML content translates automatic to my language in php

Tags: php, xml, google-calendar-api

What happens is that the text I want to work with automatically translates to dutch.
This is part of the xml:
Look careful at: **"Event status: confirmed"**

```
&lt;br&gt;Event Status: confirmed</summary><content type='html'>When: Wed Aug 26, 2015&lt;br /&gt;
```

So what I basically do is get the object in php and print the object. 
The problem is that the text is in dutch now.
I have no idea why. See the image beneath.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/c08efd3bce0aff804ea747de4d27acd9.png]

```
if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url))===false){
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
   print_r($data);
```

Where I think it goes wrong: *file_get_contents();* Does someone know how I can get an English output?

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($response_xml_data);` yet? Because I think that XML of yours is being dynamically generated based on the client (or server) system settings whenever you access it through your `$map_url`

Comment: Gives me the same dutch result.

Comment: It might confirm my suspicion. In what context you manage to see it in English?

Comment: It is from google calendar. If i take the url and put it in my web browser. The data is in English.

Comment: See if [it helps](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/520367/ForcingplusGoogleplustoplusreturnplusanplusXMLplus).

Comment: Hey aedix, that site helped. Appending ?hl=en to the url worked. Thanks.

Comment: Let's make it an answer so other people might get the solution for this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `?hl=en` at your URL request, thus forcing the API to return it into the language you want.